# Как TypeScript узнает о потенциальной рантайм-ошибке, если если он рантайма не предоставляет?

Tags: typescript

Только начинаю разбираться с TypeScript.

Есть такой код

```
let arr : number[] | number = [1, 2, 3];

function logOut(arr: number[]) : void {
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item);
    });
}

logOut(arr);
```

Переменная `arr` может быть либо числом, либо массивом чисел. Я явно устанавливаю ее в массив чисел.

Функция `logOut` принимает в качестве единственного параметра только массив чисел.

Сейчас все в порядке, никаких ошибок нет, код выполняется без проблем.

Изменяю код, добавляю условное переопределение `arr`: в 50% случаев `arr` станет равна `100` вместо `[1, 2, 3]`

```
let arr : number[] | number = [1, 2, 3];

arr = Math.random() > 0.5 ? arr : 100;

function logOut(arr: number[]) : void {
    arr.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item);
    });
}

logOut(arr);
```

Это вполне устраивает компилятор в случае с переменной `arr`, поскольку явно сказано, что она может быть как массивом чисел, так и числом, но это не может устроить функцию `logOut`, так как она принимает на вход *только* массив чисел. И, справедливо, строка с вызовом функции в TypeScript Playground подсвечивается красным.

Отсюда **вопрос**: как, не добавляя никаких рантайм-проверок, компилятор узнал, что при вызове функции может возникнуть ошибка? Как он это понял по одной лишь добавленной строке? У него настолько сильный статический анализатор? `Math.random()` заставляет его включить "режим повышенной бдительности"? А что будет в менее очевидных случаях, если я случайно, сам того не замечая, напишу такой код, в котором переменная будет изменять свой тип в рантайме? TypeScript каким-то магическим образом предусматривает все возможные варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выражения `Math.random() > 0.5 ? arr : 100;` вычисляется тип возвращаемого значения

В данном случае он будет `number[] | number`, что соответствует типу объявленной ранее переменной, поэтому результат можно в нее сохранить.

Далее идет простая проверка, что тип переменной `number[] | number` шире чем тип параметра `number[]`. Так как компилятор не может точно сказать какой тип будет при передаче - выбрасывается указанная ошибка.

Comment: *Для выражения Math.random() > 0.5 ? arr : 100; вычисляется тип возвращаемого значения* - данное действие будет производиться только для всех мест, где идет присвоение (`=`)? Или есть еще какие-то другие "инициаторы"?

Comment: И что касаемо случаев, когда тип возвращаемого значения тоже зависит тем или иным образом от какой-то, скажем, переменной, значение которой будет известно только в рантайме? Например, если это user-input

Comment: @smellyshovel, все типы известны на этапе компиляции. В случае user-input и подобных функций тип присваивается `any` и этот тип можно присвоить любой переменной, и в любую переменную. С ним проверка во время компиляции не работает.